# Screenshot shows black image in device - cocos2d-iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Below code generates screenshot in my Game which works fine in Simulator but when i check in device,it shows black image.
here is my code to generate screenshot .

```
CCDirector *director = (CCDirector *) [CCDirector sharedDirector];
screenshootimage = [director screenshotUIImage];
appDelegate.screenshootimage = [Utility getImageFromView];
imgsprite = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:screenshootimage.CGImage key:@"s"];

 - (UIImage*) screenshotUIImage
  {
    CGSize displaySize  = [self displaySizeInPixels];
    CGSize winSize      = [self winSizeInPixels];

    //Create buffer for pixels
    GLuint bufferLength = displaySize.width * displaySize.height * 4;
    GLubyte* buffer = (GLubyte*)malloc(bufferLength);

    //Read Pixels from OpenGL
    glReadPixels(0, 0, displaySize.width, displaySize.height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
    //Make data provider with data.
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, bufferLength, NULL);

    //Configure image
    int bitsPerComponent = 8;
    int bitsPerPixel = 32;
    int bytesPerRow = 4 * displaySize.width;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
    CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(displaySize.width, displaySize.height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

    uint32_t* pixels = (uint32_t*)malloc(bufferLength);
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, winSize.width, winSize.height, 8, winSize.width * 4, CGImageGetColorSpace(iref), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, displaySize.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    switch (deviceOrientation_)
    {
        case CCDeviceOrientationPortrait: break;
        case CCDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(180));
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -displaySize.width, -displaySize.height);
            break;
        case CCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-90));
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -displaySize.height, 0);
            break;

        case CCDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90));
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, displaySize.height-displaySize.width, -displaySize.height);
            break;
    }

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, displaySize.width, displaySize.height), iref);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *outputImage = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef] autorelease];

    //Dealloc
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGImageRelease(iref);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    free(buffer);
    free(pixels);

    return outputImage;
}

+ (UIImage*)getImageFromView
{
    // Create a graphics context with the target size
    // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
    // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
    //CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    CGSize newImageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(newImageSize.height, newImageSize.width);

    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO,1.0);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Iterate over every window from back to front
    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) 
    {
        if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
        {
            // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
            // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
            CGContextSaveGState(context);
            // Center the context around the window's anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].y, [window center].x);
            CGContextRotateCTM( context, degreesToRadian( -90 ) ) ;
            // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);

            // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                                  -imageSize.height *[[window layer] anchorPoint].y,
                                  -imageSize.width *[[window layer] anchorPoint].x);

            // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
            [[window layer] renderInContext:context];

            // Restore the context
            CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        }
    }

    // Retrieve the screenshot image
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

any help ?!

**NOTE:** It also works fine in `iPad` Device, only problem is with iPhone Device.

Comment: When and how do you call this screenshot method? It has to be on the same thread the GL is working on and it has to be when the buffer is full (after all the drawing is done), the correct buffer must be bound, multisampling could also be an issue (call it after the buffers are resolved and the target buffer must be bound).

Comment: i call this method when the game is over 
- (void) showGameOver { CCDirector *director = (CCDirector *) [CCDirector sharedDirector];
screenshootimage = [director screenshotUIImage];
appDelegate.screenshootimage = [Utility getImageFromView];
imgsprite = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:screenshootimage.CGImage key:@"s"]; }

but it works well in ipad device why ?!

Comment: It would seem my question wasn't clear.. "When" as I described according to frame state (beginning, end) and where as to what thread are you calling this thing on. If those things are not set correctly it might still work but it is gambling and can depend on devices. You may check if the current context is correct, also if you get some GL errors... For instance if you want a screenshot after some specific event you might set some bool value to true for which you ask after all drawing code is done and if it is true create a screenshot...